# CYPHER/NEO4J: Counting and removing duplicates from pattern comprehension list results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to combine count and distinct with comprehension list and keep getting errors.

I think this explains what I'd like to do, though I'm aware it does not work:

```
Match (n) WHERE n.id={id}
RETURN n {.id, ems: [(n)<-[:LOTS_OF_PATHS*]-()<-[:EVEN_MORE_PATHS*]-(m) | id:     distinct m.id, count: count(distinct m)]}
```

Have also tried with some collects in there

```
Match (n) WHERE n.id={id}
RETURN n {.id, ems: [(n)<-[:LOTS_OF_PATHS*]-()<-[:EVEN_MORE_PATHS*]-(m) | collect(distinct m {id:m.id}), count: count(distinct m)]}
```

I'm actually collecting the comprehension lists, and ideally would like no repeats within each array, and ideally no repeats amongst the sum of collects.

```
Match (n) WHERE n.id={id}
RETURN n {.id, collect([(n)<-[:LOTS_OF_PATHS*]-()<-[:EVEN_MORE_PATHS*]-(m) | distinct m.id])+ collect([(n)<-[:OTHER_PATHS*]-()<-[:MORE_PATHS*]-(o) | distinct o.id]) as distinct_ems_and_os}
```

The count is less important as I can count the array, but would love to understand it a bit better.

Comment: Note that at present you can't use DISTINCT for the resulting elements of a pattern comprehension. You'd be better off using OPTIONAL MATCH followed by a WITH collect(DISTINCT ...)

Answer (score 2):

This query (which does not use the fairly limited pattern comprehension) might work for you:

```
MATCH (n)<-[:LOTS_OF_PATHS*]-()<-[:EVEN_MORE_PATHS*]-(m)
WHERE n.id = $id
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT m.id) AS ems
RETURN {id: $id, ems: ems, count: SIZE(ems)}
```

NOTE: [variable-length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) have exponential complexity. You may need to set a reasonable upper bound on the number of hops to avoid running out of memory or long execution times.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response CyberSam! I read somewhere that pattern comprehension is faster and I need to collect so much from so many patterns that comprehension list seems more suited for the job, else I end up with lots of unwinds and the risk of unbound nodes when I mess up my optional match variables and get null matches. For now I am fixing the resulting arrays, but would love to know if it's doable with comprehension list.

Comment: I do not think pattern comprehensions can be more efficient  (and may not work at all) for this use case. There is no need for `UNWIND` or `OPTIONAL MATCH` here either, so I cannot address any other concerns you may have. If you have a concrete issue, you can create another question with full details.

Comment: To add on, the efficiency in pattern comprehensions is that it takes care of the resulting cardinality for you. It's the equivalent of an OPTIONAL MATCH + a collect(), it's just a bit more concise, and can be used as an expression which makes it flexible. It's harder to shoot yourself in the foot if you need several of these (back to back MATCH or OPTIONAL MATCHes can create cartesian products). Aside from these points, there shouldn't be any efficiency gains from using these over OPTIONAL MATCH + collect().

Comment: Thanks! I am doing a lot back to back because stepping out would require a lot of gathering of parameters to step back in.  I would need optional matches to avoid filtering, and then unwind after sums of collects - and changing the cardinality messes up the speed. I have found pattern comprehension with nesting faster and clearer too. I hoped to avoid duplicates with variable length, but when it does not affect cardinality I can fix the array. DISTINCT would have been great in comprehension list, but I am likely just not understanding the inner workings at all. Thanks so much for your advice!